# Touch Events in Vue 2.0

Tags: vue.js, swipe, vuejs2

I'm using Vue 2.0 and I should work with swipe gestures. I have checked that there is one official plugin (named [vue-touch](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-touch)) but as they say, Vue 2.0 is not supported yet.

Which libraries are available for Vue 2.0 to implement touch events?

Comment: I don't have a clear-cut answer for you by maybe using this in combination with vue could help you? http://hammerjs.github.io/ You could probably write your own directives for it making it a lot easier to use with Vue.

Comment: I couldn't think a way to use directives for this purpose. the events of [directives](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) are limited and i think we can't catch the event in directive itself. If it is possible, i would be happy to see this.

Comment: there is already a vue2 branch -> [vue2-touch-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-touch-events)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I checked and there already is a vue-touch for Vue 2.0, it is on another branch though:

> This branch is only compatible with Vue 1.0. For the Vue 2.0 compatible rewrite, see the next branch

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-touch/tree/next

Comment: Is there another project may be? It seems that they are not working anymore on github.

Comment: important note: Vue-touch has still serious issues in iOS that caused us to use something else.

Comment: `vue2-touch-events`made an important release 9 days ago and it is currently the most popular package to manage touch events in Vue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-touch-events

Answer (score 8):

**You can easily use Hammer directly in Vue. [Create Vue directives](https://lisilinhart.info/posts/touch-interaction-vue/)** to wrap the Hammer touch events you're interested in. Do this once for your whole app. This is easy and shouldn't put you off.

Vue2-hammer (1600 weekly npm downloads) also wraps hammer but for the moment I'm choosing to do this directly. Vue2-touch-events (5000 weekly npm downloads) does not leverage Hammer, which seems brave.

Comment: hammer.js unfortunately seems to have gone pretty stagnant. According to this thread (https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1197) it looks like it's future is still being decided.